# Fetch Current Access Token in JHipster UAA based Microservice Applications

Tags: oauth-2.0, microservices, jhipster, access-token, cloudfoundry-uaa

I have a JHipster Microservices having UAA based authentication (OAuth 2.0). I have set certain claims in token through `IatTokenEnhancer`. I want to use the value of these claims in each request. `How can I fetch the access token from current request?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Token is accessible via `SecurityContext`. Following is the code:

```
public static Optional<String> getCurrentUserToken() {
    SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    return Optional.ofNullable(securityContext.getAuthentication())
        .filter(authentication -> authentication.getDetails() instanceof OAuth2AuthenticationDetails)
        .map(authentication -> ((OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) authentication.getDetails()).getTokenValue());
}
```